# Vacuum polarization of dark matter candidates

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum, dark-matter

Can a dark matter particle (axions, for instance, but the question applies to any valid candidate for dark matter) induce QED vacuum polarization effects even if being electrically neutral and with no observable magnetic or electric dipolar moment?

Answer (score 1):

Dark matter is typically thought of as being an elementary particle (not a composite particle made of other particles) that is neutral. Thus it would not interact at all with photons and wouldn't be charged under QED. It wouldn't feel the vacuum polarization effects of QED since it doesn't talk to real nor virtual photons.

This situation is distinct from the case of a neutron which while neutral, is made up of quarks. The quarks are able to interact electromagnetically through a dipole interaction.